# Why don't ladder operators mix angular momentum eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

The crucial step in the typical (see e.g. Sakurai Chapter 3.5.1) proof of the eigenvalues of the angular momentum operators $J^2$ and $J_z$ is (after defining the ladder operators $J_\pm :+ J_x \pm iJ_y$ and showing that they map an angular momentum eigenstate $|j,m \rangle$ into the $m+1$ eigenspace but not out of the $j$ eigenspace) to assert that each eigenspace of ($j,m$) is one-dimensional so that, for example, $J_+|j,m \rangle = c|j,m+1 \rangle$ for some $c$.

But obviously it's not a priori clear that the ($j,m$) is one-dimensional and of course, in general, it need not be. Presumably the author is tacitly suggesting that these $J_\pm$ don't "mix" eigenstates. That is, if in reality we have a CSCO including some observable(s) $A$ with quantum number(s) $a$, then $|a,j,m \rangle$ are our complete eigenbasis. Thus it should be possible to show that
$$\langle a',j,m|J_\pm|a,j,m \rangle = 0$$
but I cannot seem to see how to do this. If $[J_\pm,A] = 0$ this would be immediate, but is it true that $[J^2,A] = [J_z,A] = 0$ implies this perhaps?

Comment: The point of finding the eigenstates of $\hat{J}^2$ and $\hat{J}_z$ is to fully characterize the angular degrees of freedom of a system.  We can always use these states as a basis for the *angular* part of the wave function, whether they end up being eigenstates of the Hamiltonian or not.  So, it's not true that $|jm\rangle$ is one-dimensional in the *full* Hilbert space, but it is one-dimensional for the *angular* degrees of freedom. Then, the operators for any *other* degree of freedom necessarily commute with all $\hat{L}$'s, and so we can choose a *basis*, $|j,m,\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: However, if the Hamiltonian depends on angular degrees of freedom, then the $|j,m\rangle$ states might mix with each other.  I'm trying to figure out exactly what your question is, so do my comments help clarify things? For me, it seems like the restriction of developing a basis for just the angular degrees of freedom answers your question, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand what you mean by "angular degrees of freedom", or the angular part of the wavefunction? Most generally (for what I care about right now), we have (let's restrict to) one particle, perhaps with spin, perhaps not. There exists a generator of rotation $\boldsymbol{J}$ on that particle's Hilbert space and we can then develop, using properties of rotations, the spectrum of this and associated (like $J^2$) operators. My question is to what extent or why, in this "most general" case, we can take the $j,m$ eigenspaces of $J^2, J_z$ as one-dimensional or, if they're...

Comment: ...not, why we don't mix when going up the ladder? @march

Comment: I suspect that the answer to this question, then, lies in the lie algebra theory. I don't know a lot of the details, so I can't write an answer, but the lie algebra for the 3D rotation group is generated by the three components $\hat{J}_n$ of the angular momentum operator, and there is one (independent) Casimir operator $\hat{J}^2$. Then, we look for the unitary representations of the algebra, which are exactly the total-$j$ subspaces with their corresponding matrix operator representations.  I think the fact that $|j,m\rangle$ is non-degenerate comes out of this basic theory.

Comment: Non-degenerate $|j, m\rangle$ mean that the representation is irreducible. In Lie angebra theory, it is proven that (almost?) any representation can be decomposed into a direct sum of irreducible representations.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the $z$ direction. You have
$[J_x,A] = [J_y,A] = [J_z,A] = 0$ for a rotationally invariant system, so $[J_\pm,A] = 0$.  Since $[J_i,J_j] \neq 0$ for $i\neq j$ you choose to
simultaneously diagonalize just $J_z$ and $J^2$, but the commutators of
all the components of $\vec J$ commute with the Hamiltonian for the
rotationally invariant system.

Edited to add:

Normally, if you are using angular momentum algebra to simplify
matrix elements, you want eigenstates of a rotationally invariant operator.
You choose $J_z$ to be an arbitrary convenient direction.
If you want to break rotational symmetry in your basis states, then
the standard results won't hold.

Here's a trivial example which shows how $J_\pm$ can mix the states.
Take different 3-d Harmonic oscillator potentials depending on $J_z$
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p^2}{2M}
+\frac{1}{2}M\omega_0^2 r^2 \left [ 1  + \frac{\alpha}{\hbar}L_z \right ] \,.
\end{equation}
Obviously this $H$ commutes with $L^2$ and $L_z$, and separates,
so the eigenstates are products of spherical harmonics and radial functions,
$R_{n\ell m}(r) Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)$.

The radial functions satisfy
\begin{equation}
\left [
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2M} \frac{d^2}{dr^2}
+ \frac{\hbar^2}{2M}\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2}
+\frac{1}{2}M\omega_0^2 r^2 ( 1  + \alpha m ) - E_{n\ell m} \right
] R_{n\ell m}(r)\,.
\end{equation}

The lowest energy $\ell=1$ eigenstates, which I will label
$|n=0,\ell=1,m\rangle$, obviously have different radial functions for
different $m$ values since the $r^2$ term has a different factor. If you
operate on the $|n=0,\ell=1,m=-1\rangle$ state with the raising operator,
you will change $Y_{1,-1}$ to $Y_{1,0}$, but that new state is not the
$|n=1,\ell=1,m=0\rangle$ state. So obviously if you break translational
invariance, then the angular momentum operators corresponding to
rotations where the symmetry is broken will not keep you in a degenerate
subspace. So basically, no one uses these broken symmetry states if they
want to use the raising and lowering operators on their basis.

Comment: But who said anything about a rotationally invariant problem?

Comment: You did when you said $J_z$ and $J^2$ commuted with A.

Comment: Couldn't that occur for a problem in which the $z$ direction is picked out as special (e.g. via a magnetic field)?

Comment: @EE18, the fact that $\left [ J_\pm , J^2 \right ] = 0$ implies that they would not be mapping out of the $j$ eigenspace, regardless of whether your entire system respects spherical symmetry or not.

Comment: Absolutely, but you're saying that we can or can't get guarantee that there isn't mixing between different $n$ quantum numbers as we go up the ladder in a given $j$ eigenspace?

Comment: You can choose a basis that corresponds to the rotationally invariant problem. You could also choose a basis that does not. So for example you could have the usual rotationally invariant case with states $|n j m\rangle$. You can of course change bases to different linear combinations of say $n=1$ and $n=2$ for different $m$ values, making a new set of orthogonal states. Those states will be the eigenvectors of some Hamiltonian with good $J^2$ and $J_z$, and obviously when you apply the angular momentum raising operator you will not get the correct raised eigenstate.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the above comment.

Comment: You originally only asked about the $j$ eigenspace, which you easily accepted the argument above. We care about angular momentum eigenstates because $[J^2, \mathcal H] = 0 = [J_\pm,\mathcal H]$ too, because the Coulomb problem is spherically symmetric and so there would not be mixing of $n$ either.